# Configuring event log - RHEL

Tags: linux, syslog, configure

In the [Readme](https://github.com/balabit/eventlog), it mentions to invoke `./configure` before `make` & `make install` of eventlog on RHELinux.

But, I do not see `configure` script except `configure.in`.

---

Do I need to rename `configure.in` to `configure` and run the script?

Comment: You need to ask the maintainer of the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run the autogen.sh script:

This should create the necessary `configure` and `make` scripts.

Comment: Make sure you have the libtools RPM installed (or you'll get issues).

Comment: 1) `./autogen.sh` would suffice? 2) Is it `libtool` or `libtools`?

Comment: 1. If you run the `autogen.sh` script and end up with the `configure`, `make` and `install` scripts. That'll be all that's required. If they're not created, it will most likely be because the `libtool` package isn't installed

Comment: Installed ` libtool.x86_64 0:2.4.2-22.el7_3` would that suffice?

Comment: That's the one. It ships as a base package from RHEL to install from the OS repo.

Comment: Am actually looking for `eventlog_0.2.12` version, which version of eventlog is this? `0.2.13`